# How to refresh a specific div content along with the link id when clicked on a link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to refresh the div content by clicking on `href` link along with the id(named as data), my actual problem is I'm unable to get the id value with in the script because it is passed with in the function. How to pass the data variable in my php to script? Please check my code below and help me out to solve this. img_div is id of my div which is to be refreshed

PHP:

```
function printSubDir($dir, $path){       
    global $data;
    $data = $path.''.$dir;
    echo "<li><span class=\"toggle\"><a href='asset1.php?data=$data' id='refresh'>$dir</a></span>";
    createDir($path.$dir."/");
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#refresh').click(function(){
            $('#img_div').load('asset1.php #img_div', function() {
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: just to confirm you want the href attribute of the link right ?
var href = $(this).attr('href')

Answer (score 1):

Hi assuming that your variable is $data.You can a php variable in javascript like the following

```
  <?php
     $data = "Value of your variable";
    ?>
    <script>

    // now a javascript variable data stores the value of your php variable
    var data= "<?php echo $data?>";

    </script>
```

I Hope this heps

Comment: Thanks, but my variable $data is with in the function loop how to pass that variable in script? please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the id into the function call:

```
<?php
  echo "<a onClick='handleClick($id)'>$dir</a>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, how to use this can you explain me briefly?  @gazdagergo